When and where is the generic attribute in ResolvableType assigned?
When I debugged the spring source code, I discovered a strange problem: As shown in the figure, before the getInterfaces() method is called in the for loop, generics is still null, but after entering the getInterfaces() method, it is still in the first line, then generics has a value again.
before entering the getInterfaces() method
after entering the getInterfaces() method
When and where is the generic attribute in ResolvableType assigned
